# How to parse a string that contains E- notation into decimal

Tags: c#, bigdecimal

I'd like to return convert string to decimal, but few rows are throwing exception (see code below).

```
Func<DataRow, string, decimal?> getFieldNullableDecimal = (row, field) =>
{
   if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((row[field] ?? string.Empty).ToString()))
   {
      var data = row[field].ToString();
      return decimal.Parse(data);           //--this line is throwing exception
   }
 }
```

The error is being thrown when the value returned by the database is of the following form: **-2.8421709430404E-14**

What I thinking of doing is just to check whether the string as "**E-**". I'll then convert both parts in number then multiply them. However, before I do that, I'd like to know whether there exists a method that already does it.

Thanks for helping

Comment: What's the datatype in the database? Ideally, just avoid doing any string manipulation at all...

Comment: is the conversion to string really necessary? It seems as though you have structured data coming from the DB… either you already have a number in which case you don't have to do anything, or you have some data structure which you can probably convert to a number directly (at least I would expect that in any relatively sane DBMS API…)

Comment: `decimal.Parse("-2.8421709430404E-14", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float);` but the better option would be to use [`SqlDataReader.GetDecimal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdecimal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  method, if you are interacting with a SQL Server DB.

Comment: @JonSkeet, the datatype in the database is `float`

Comment: Right, so stop calling `ToString`, and fetch the value as a `double` or a `decimal`. (Look at the type of `row[field]` in the debugger just to check, and cast to that type in your code. Note that if it's `double` and you wanted `decimal`, you should consider changing the data type in the database...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use NumberStyles.AllowExponent and NumberStyles.Float. For example:

```
Decimal.Parse("-2.8421709430404E-14", 
              NumberStyles.AllowExponent | NumberStyles.Float);
```

Something like this:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((row[field] ?? string.Empty).ToString()))
{
    return decimal.Parse(row[field].ToString(), 
                         NumberStyles.AllowExponent | NumberStyles.Float);
}
```

Please note, this assumes you have the System.Globalization namespace in your using statements. For example:

```
using System.Globalization;
```

Alternatively, as John Skeet is point out, you should not need to convert it to a string and then to decimal.

If it is a Float in the database, the equivalent in the CLR is Double. So you could just try and cast it to a Double. For example:

```
return (double)row[field];
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error after I added the above code. And this is the value that was returned from the database "-2.8421709430404E-14"

Comment: I have seen that in my testing. Try `NumberStyles.AllowExponent | NumberStyles.Float` as the number styles.

Comment: While this will work, I view it as a "solution" to a self-made problem: parsing a string value which shouldn't be a string value in the first place. There's simply no need to convert to a string and back here.

Comment: @JonSkeet I see. The equivalent of float in the CLR is Double. So would return Convert.ToDouble(row[field]) work here?

Comment: I didn't write the code, I'm just fixing this problem. However, even myself I didn't think that I could just convert the type from object straight to the expected type without transiting by string.

Comment: @Donal: I'd just cast it to `double` rather than using `Convert.ToDouble`. (I'd expect that to work.) But if the OP wants a `decimal`, that suggests that there's a problem somewhere - either he should be using `double`, or the database should be using a decimal floating point type...

Comment: Please look at the whole FUNC<>, it's supposed to return decimal.

Comment: @Richard77 it should implicitly convert it to a decimal. If not it is just another cast.